# How to add report section to the Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to implement a report section in Django admin. This would mean adding a custom section in the admin homepage where instead of a list of models I would see a list of reports. I want to use Django's admin tables with filters, sorting, everything if possible.

What would be the "best" way of achieving this? I realize this is a "big" question so I'm not asking for code snippets necessarily, a summary of needed actions would be just fine :)

P.S. Be report I mean a "made up" model by custom queries (queryset or how it's called).

P.S.2 Maybe this question should be something like: How to use Django admin tables functionality in own admin view?

P.S.3 Or maybe there is a way of providing to the existing admin interface my own data. This way I don't have to do anything else. I just want to say instead of a model take this data and display it  in a nice table which I can sort, filter etc etc.

Comment: what do you mean by "list of reports"? Do you have some specific kind of report in mind?

Comment: What do you mean with **reports**? You can prepare a custom page with django and make any kind of anything you want. But using default django filters in a such view and template is not possible. But you can easily write our filters.

How to [skip admin index page and going to a specific one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12424461/257972)

Comment: I mean you have now in the Django admin homepage the app name as the section's header (with blue background) and then the list of models of that app. I want a section with the Reports header and then a list of reports like Sales, Best Sellers... just about any table that doesn't have a model behind it but it's made up by some code. Instead of an actual model I would have a "made up" model behind.

Comment: You can build "mock" models: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813637/django-how-to-generate-an-admin-panel-without-models

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So you are attempting to add in new pages into the django admin.

This section explains to you exactly how you can do so - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites

The basic idea is to add in new urls that you want in your `urls.py` as if you are adding urls for your "front end" pages.  The key difference is that these new urls you are adding should start with `^admin/` and would look something like `^admin/my_special_link_in_admin` and this url will point to your own custom view function at a location you so prefer.

E.g.

```
(r'^admin/my_special_link_in_admin/$', 'my_custom_admin_app.views.special_admin_page'),
```

So this is the way for complete customization.  There's a very good tutorial which I refer to here - http://brandonkonkle.com/blog/2010/oct/4/django-admin-customization-examples/

In addition, if you don't want to do too much work, consider using Django Admin Plus -  https://github.com/jsocol/django-adminplus

Or a django-admin-views - https://github.com/frankwiles/django-admin-views

Comment: Yes, I want new pages but I don't want to use my own table templates and functionality. This is huge work! :) I want the nice Django admin to work for custom data also, not just model data :D

Comment: Yup. I get it. Use https://github.com/jsocol/django-adminplus as mentioned in my updated answer.

Comment: Will this adminplus take of my hands the need to write table sorting, for example?

Comment: Yes. It is 100% compatible with standard django admin functionality.  All it does - if you check out its templates here https://github.com/jsocol/django-adminplus/tree/master/adminplus/templates/adminplus - is to extend to use the standard django admin templates while permitting you to write your own queries in your custom view function, which you would need to register like this `admin.site.register_view('somepath', my_view)`

Comment: I see. This would do it, but please check out my 3rd edit to the question. Can that be done? Would be alot more fast and elegant.

Comment: I think you have to at the very least write your own custom query :-D
Otherwise, how would the page know "what to show"? If your target data source isn't a django model, you will need to decide what data you want to show, no?

Comment: Sorry for extending my question. Yes that is the only thing I want to do if possible. Write my own query, pass it to the Django admin as a "fake" model and let Django admin display it in a table. You have to agree that would be the nicest way :P

Comment: Isn't that exactly what this example shows you? https://github.com/jsocol/django-adminplus#using-adminplus

Comment: Well, I don't know, is it? I mean I want more than just writing a view. That view will create some tabular data and I need that data displayed with Django's admin table functionality? How do I do that? I mean why write code when it's already there. I just don't know how to plugin into it :)